# What is the meaning of "To have too much in your locker"

Tags: meaning

In [this video](https://youtu.be/I299Xrryhbc?t=4m46s) entitled *Daniel Sturridge surprises unsuspecting school kids*, he says 
 "You have too much in your locker"

Here is the transcript at 4 mins 55 seconds approximately:

> Daniel: What's your celebration?
>   Kid: A front flip.
>   Daniel: Huh?
>   Kid: A front flip.
>   Daniel: I can't do a front flip. You know, I was gonna say "let's do your celebration together" but obviously **this guy's got too much in his locker**.

Does it mean that the kid is very skilled or talented? If not, what does it mean ?

Comment: @Devil07 I haven't heard it either (I live in the NE US). I would assume that it is similar to the idiom "too much on your plate". I think this question needs some context as to where this expression was heard, and the context in which it was said.

Comment: You might be interested in checking out the Stack Exchange's [ell.se], which was created for users like you and questions like this one.

Comment: I would interpret it to mean "Like Fibber McGee's closet."  (Though figuratively, of course.)

Comment: I grew up in southwest US and I've never heard that one. Maybe the guy literally had too many items in his locker. If it is an idiom, it sounds like it might not be a compliment. If it is an idiom, it sounds more like the idiom, "Too many balls in the air" as in juggling too much to handle properly. –

Comment: it means he's busy: aka "a lot on his plate", perhaps implying he needs to re-proritize his projects, akin to cleaning out a locker with unused clutter.

Comment: as @Laurel said I would interpret it similarly. Think of the imagery and metaphor involved. What happens when you have too much in your locker? You get hassle. You struggle to close your locker, and when you open it things might spill out.

Comment: Maybe the video in the link below will help. That was the very first time when I heard it and few days ago again, so I decided to give it more attention. Thank you again!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I299Xrryhbc
PS: there is also big chance that he doesn't say locker haha

Comment: Just skip to 4:55.

Comment: I really can not understand how this question deserves closed as  "unclear what you're asking" !

Answer (score 2):

Watching the video (where Sturridge is talking to a primary-school boy with good gymnastics 
skills) I'd guess Sturridge really means a metaphor like

> this guy [i.e. the kid] has got too much [i.e. too many skills/tricks] in his **armoury (or arsenal)**

But he jokingly waters it down to *locker* not *armoury* as it more appropriate (and funnier) for his young audience than the more usual phrasing.